# PDF formats page margins not applied

Tags: pdf

I have recently upgraded from CiviCRM 4.6 to 4.7. I have custom PDF page formats set up for PDF letters for mailing. When I apply these custom PDF formats to the PDF letter templates, the page margins I set up in the PDF formats are not applied to the letter templates and don't display in the margins fields in the expanded template section.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to this bug, fixed in 4.7.14:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17879

Could you re-test in the latest version to see if it has been resolved?